# Proof on minimal spanning tree

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory

Suppose $T$ is a minimal spanning tree in a connected graph G. Show that either $T$ contains the $n-1$ smallest edges, or the $n-1$ smallest edges form a subgraph which contains a cycle.

Suppose $T$ is a minimal spanning tree in a connected graph $G$. Also suppose the $n-1$ smallest edges form a subgraph do not contain a cycle. Therefore since $T$ is a tree it has $n-1$ edges and since it is a minimal spanning tree, each edge in $T$ is of minimum weight. So $T$ contains $n-1$ smallest edges.

Not sure if I'm going about this proof correctly.

Comment: Why must $G'$ be connected?

Comment: @JazzyMatrix Not sure anymore. My proof is wrong but I had to turn it in.

Comment: Try to still figure it out! Math is all about practice. If you let $H$ be the subgraph given by the $n-1$ smallest edges, consider the statements contrapositive: if $T\ne H$ and $H$ is a forest, then $T$ is not minimal. All you have to do is show that $H$ must be connected, and you're done.

Comment: @JazzyMatrix Alright I try thanks